# Why does scp -scp work but not scp without that flag

Tags: sftp, scp

when I try and scp to my solaris box, I get this

unable to initialise SFTP: could not connect

unless I do scp -scp then it works.

In my sshd_config file, I have this:

Subsystem       sftp    /usr/local/libexec/sftp-server

Answer (score 3):

Apparently your "scp" try to use "sftp" first, for some reason. The "sftp" subsystem may need to be configured at both ends.